# How to use decision variable in the exponential term while using CVXPY?

Tags: python, cvxpy, cvxopt

The objective function of my optimization problem involves the exponential function of the decision variables. My code is

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import math

A = np.array([0.805156521,0.464522,0.00452762,0.00047562])
Zmax = 200
Zmin = 25
T = cp.Variable(2)

# Defining the objective function
objective = cp.Minimize((A[0]+A[1])*math.exp(T[0]) + (A[2]+A[3])*math.exp(T[1]))

# Defining the constraints
constraints = []
constraints += [cp.sum(T) == 250]
constraints += [Zmin <= T]
constraints += [T <= Zmax]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve()

# Print result.
print("\nThe optimal value is", prob.value)
print("A solution T is")
print(T.value)
```

I am getting the following error on the line where the objective function is defined:

`TypeError: must be real number, not index`

I am using default solvers in the CVXPY package. Kindly advise how to tackle this problem. Thank you. (I have already asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322170/how-to-use-decision-variable-in-the-exponential-term-while-using-cvxpy), but haven't got any response. Therefore, asking in this forum.)

Comment: Use ``cp.exp`` instead of ``math.exp``. The math module does not know how to deal with cvxpy objects.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks, it worked.